# Hide div based on url but with JS in Head

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
<div id="myelement"><p>I want hide this text if current URL contain s0dagvLc</p></div>
```

and this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('s0dagvLc') != -1) {
document.getElementById('myelement').style.display='none';
```

}

and the code work Onload but not inside Head. I tested a bunch of code without more luck. I don't understand the difference.  Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0dagvLc/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it with an event listener for [**`DOMContentLoaded`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('s0dagvLc') != -1) {
    document.getElementById('myelement').style.display='none';
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent work well,thanks. Last point I tried to hide element by class with getElementsByClassName but this don't work. Is not possible by class ?

Comment: It's because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You could access the first value in the array.. `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
<body onload="display()">
  <div id="demo"  ><p>I want hide this text if current URL contain s0dagvLc</p></div>
</body>

<script>
function display(){
    if( /fiddle/.test(window.location.host) ){
       document.getElementById("demo").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```